# Do I have microsoft visual basic for applications extensibility 5.3 in vba for excel 2007?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I recently used a macros which uses Microsoft visual basic for applications extensibility 5.3. I'm using excel 2013 while my boss who uses this macros has 2007.  I've run this my computer and other computers which has 2013 excel and they run properly. Butmy boss says he can't find  'extensibility 5.3' on his version of excel. So does it have to installed separately?

Comment: On my computer running Office 2007, it is installed and available.